# Excel sum from multiple columns where date between several columns

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I need help with excel sum calculating!

I have a table with 4 Amount Fields and 4 Date Fields
[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpE5u.jpg)

I need to Calculate sum from all amount columns which are in particular month and get a result like this:

January 2016 - Total Sum
January 2017 - Total Sum

etc...

I already try this:
=SUMIFS(A2:A9,B2:B9,">="&"09/01/2016",B2:B9,"<="&"09/30/2016")

for finding the sum for column A between dates in column B, but i cant figure out how to accomplish calculating sum for all Amount Columns which are between all Date Columns...

Thank You in advance for your help...

Comment: What you're requesting isn't clear. Perhaps post another image with faked results in the format you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(A2:G9,B2:H9,">="&"09/01/2016",B2:H9,"<="&"09/30/2016")
```

Note how the columns are offset by one.

[image]

Comment: Probably unlikely :) but theoretically that formula could "sum" the date columns if the corresponding amounts are the same as a serial number of a date in the relevant month! Perhaps use SUMPRODUCT and check row 1 so that only amount columns can be summed, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:G9,(TEXT(B2:H9,"mmm-yyyy")="Sep-2016")*(LEFT(A1:G1,6)="Amount"))`